# Manage files left by uninstalled apps?

Tags: sd-card, file-management

I just realized that when an app has the "SD card access" it has access to the entire SD card and all the other apps that use the SD card. I would have assumed that each Apps data is "sandboxed" like on an iPhone.

So, once I delete the App that accessed the SD card I noticed that it doesn't always delete the corresponding files it created on the SD card. In one case I installed a Linux Emulator that created 4 gig file and when it came to installing the rest of the Linux it failed. So naturally I uninstalled the application.

Out of curiosity I looked on the SD card found the file in some randomly named directory.

So the big question is, is there a way to manage the deletion of those files as opposed to having to check your entire SD card everytime you uninstall an Application?

PS: My device is Rooted

Comment: I don't believe Android keeps a list of "what file was created by which app".

That being said, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try **Clean Master** from Google Play Store. I had it for quite some time now, when you delete apps it will pop up asking you whether you want to delete residual files as well (if there are any). Also it will scan your SD Card and Phone for any rubbish.

Comment: Just deleted Clean Master as it kept going into portrait mode even when I had it locked to landscape, but thanks for the tip